# MY SQL Partitioning advice

Tags: mysql, database, hash, partitioning, sharding

We are currently deciding on a partitioning scheme for a table in our MySQL database. We have multiple shards and we route all of a single users records to one shard. We also want to partition the table itself by userid. We are somewhat new to partitioning and would like some feedback as to which type of partition to use and how often we will likely need to maintain the partition.

We did some simple tests using partitioning by key, linear key, hash and linear hash. In our tests it seems like hash is the fastest option for insertion and it also seems to give us the best distribution using randomly generated userids. While reading the documentation, however, we read that linear hash is better if you want to merge or optimize partitions but we noticed it is a lot slower on insertion. We don’t really understand why we would ever need to merge or optimize partitions so we aren’t sure how much of a consideration this should be.

Also… we are planning to use the maximum number of partitions (1000 I think) because we don’t see any negative to this approach and it should give us the best performance by limiting the number of records per partition to the maximum degree. Is there anything we should be considering when deciding on the number of partitions or is ok to simply use 1000 partitions?
Does anybody have any advice on this?

Comment: Have you benchmarked? This is a pretty big step that's unnecessary for probably 99.9% of use cases.

Comment: I'm doing some bench-marking and mostly focused on data distribution and I can see that hash and linear hash are quiet the same as of data distribution but as of performance seems like hash out performs all the others.

Comment: What kind of writes are you doing? Is it time based log data per user or is it changes to one users data?

Comment: This is mainly a mail meta data table which is used to store user's mail information (not the body). The table is pretty equally read/write heavy since new mail is constantly coming in, mail is being deleted, and mail meta data is being updated (read/unread/flagged/etc.) while users are listing their mailboxes or using the metadata to seed IMAP responses prior to downloading the physical messages.

The system will support millions of users so we are employing both a sharding and a partitioning strategy.

Comment: Didn't I give you a "no" answer on some other forum?

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?106,630625,630633

Comment: @RickJames I posted some more information on the My SQL forum
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?106,630625,630682#msg-630682

Comment: Thanks Rick , me and Drew are looking at what you said and we will come back to you shortly

Comment: (nothing since Apr 28)

Comment: @RickJames I updated the forum question http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?106,630625,631998#msg-631998
I'll be happy to hear your ideas about what we decided to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anybody who may be interested about this topic , here is my experience :

We finally decided not to use MYSQL portioning and instead using database sharding.
The reason for that is: no matter how good you implement the portioning there is still the fact that data needs to indexed and brought into the memory when needed and for our system which is handling up to 500,000 user's emails this can simply become a major hardware issue over the time as people receive mail and will force you to buy more expensive hardware .

Also there is another hidden cost in MYSQL which is the altering tables schema which can simply become impossible if you have a big table and limited resources. After using MSSQL and Oracle in real world scenario I was NOT really impressed by the way MYSQL handles metadata updates and indexing.

So the short answer would be do not use portioning for you database unless you are sure that you won't have major schema changes to your table/indexes and also your table will not grow too big.

Although I have to say if you  design a good index for your system(be very careful with primary keys because that is your clustered index in MYSQL and your queries will be much more efficient if you query on primary key index) you may not really need portioning at all (right now on one of our installations we have a table with +450,000,000 records and it is very fast when you use the primary key index to query the data)

Another point is if there is a chronology in your data and you always have a date range to query it is good idea to use partitioning if your database does not grow too big and if you are intending to delete the old data after a while (like a log rotation,...) partitioning may be the best option because you can simply drop the partition instead of writing a delete process.

Hope this will help you making the right decision.